# How to deploy vuejs code to a public website?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web

I made a Vue js app using d3.js and a couple of JSON files. I now need to deploy my code to a public website to be viewed 24/7. I understand nobody is going to do this for me but if someone couple points me in the right direction that would be great. I tried using GitHub pages and google sites but those dont allow for javascript libraries and npm packages. I linked my GitHub repository so yall can view the code. Thank you for any help. https://github.com/BrennanAdams/BrennanAdams.github.io.git

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy your site by using firebase
Make sure you install firebase tools

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Check You're logged in firebase by

```
firebase login
```

cd into your vue project’s root directory,

Run npm run build in your root directory so that Vue builds your project for production. This will create a dist folder with everything you need to deploy… we’ll point Firebase to the dist folder in a sec.

Run the command-

```
firebase init
```

Select your the hosting option, and select the appropriate firebase project.

Run

```
firebase deploy
```

Here we go you can view your site in public

Comment: First you need to create a project in the firebase application, then config into you project, then go to project directory, then use these comments. If it is working please " upvote and make it as a correct answer" .

Answer (score 1):

You can also deploy your site in [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/)

I hope you will get step by step process from these two docs

- [Build, deploy, & run
  Vue on Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/with/vue/)
- [How to Deploy a Vue Site](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/11/30/how-to-deploy-a-vue-site/)

Comment: Here is [freeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-deploy-a-react-application-to-netlify-363b8a98a985/) tutorial